# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Apache POI Workbook.create

Tags: java, apache, excel, maven, poi

When I try to call method Workbook.create() with new FileInputStream or other parameters (File, DirectoryNode etc.) I get error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"

My code:

```
public class ExcelTemplatesUtils {
public static ByteArrayOutputStream getExcelBytesByTemplate(String templatePath, Map<String, String> data, String startSymbol, String endSymbol, String defaultValue) throws IOException {
    Workbook book = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(templatePath)); //crushed here
    Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator = book.sheetIterator();
    sheetIterator.forEachRemaining(
            (sheet) -> sheet.rowIterator().forEachRemaining(
                    (row) -> row.forEach(
                            cell -> {
                                cell.setCellValue(replaceTemplSubStr(cell.getStringCellValue(), data, startSymbol, endSymbol, defaultValue));
                            }
                    )
            )
    );
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    book.write(byteOutput);
    book.close();
    return byteOutput;
}
```

Error log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/compress/utils/InputStreamStatistics



            at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.<init>(ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.java:64)

            at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.openZipStream(ZipHelper.java:178)

            at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:104)

            at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:307)

            at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:146)

            at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:256)

            at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:221)

            at com.sbt.salary.mp.ui.utils.ExcelTemplatesUtils.getExcelBytesByTemplate(ExcelTemplatesUtils.java:19)

            at com.sbt.salary.mp.ui.utils.ExcelTemplatesUtils.getExcelBytesByTemplate(ExcelTemplatesUtils.java:45)

            at com.sbt.salary.mp.ui.utils.ExcelTemplatesUtilsTest.test_excel_template_filling_success(ExcelTemplatesUtilsTest.java:25)

            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Проверьте, подключена ли библиотека [commons-compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/) версии не ниже 1.17.